# mysql fulltext search not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

So I want to implement a better search functionality using fulltext search, however it is not behaving as expected. it will return no results, or results i would not consider as relevant.

Firstly I have checked:

> show variables like 'ft_min%'

...returns as 4

So I have a database full of game titles. A good example of a search is "assassins creed". In the database they are actually stored as "Assassin's Creed" (note apostrophe). So if I do the following query:

> SELECT g_name, MATCH(g_name) AGAINST ('assassins creed') AS score FROM
>   tgmp_games WHERE MATCH(g_name) AGAINST ('assassins creed') LIMIT 15

Returns results fine (some below)

...but with the search script, it uses a JqueryUI autocomplete dropdown, and when submitting a query for anything with fewer characters than an entire word it comes back empty

> SELECT g_name, MATCH(g_name) AGAINST ('assass') AS score FROM
>   tgmp_games WHERE MATCH(g_name) AGAINST ('assass') LIMIT 15

I have also read that the number of rows in the database can have an effect if its too low, but theres 25k rows in there so it should be fine. What am I doing wrong?

Output of the results I CAN get, but more interested in how I can get the part search term to return some results.

```
Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassins Creed III
    [score] => 15.406005859375
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => The Witcher 2: Assassins of Kings
    [score] => 8.46316719055176
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Tenchu: Shadow Assassins
    [score] => 8.46316719055176
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => The Witcher 2: Assassins of Kings - Enhanced Edition
    [score] => 8.27909851074219
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin\'s Creed
    [score] => 6.84770059585571
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin\'s Creed III
    [score] => 6.84770059585571
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin's Creed II
    [score] => 6.84770059585571
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin's Creed: Revelations ...
    [score] => 6.77157783508301
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin\'s Creed: Revelations
    [score] => 6.77157783508301
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood
    [score] => 6.77157783508301
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin's Creed: Bloodlines
    [score] => 6.77157783508301
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin's Creed II: Discovery
    [score] => 6.77157783508301
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin\'s Creed III: Liberation
    [score] => 6.77157783508301
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin's Creed: Altair's Chronicles
    [score] => 6.69712924957275
)

Array
(
    [g_name] => Assassin's Creed II:  Bonfire of the Vanities
    [score] => 6.69712924957275
)
```

Also the order of this is odd, as "The Witcher 2" is coming above other "Assassin's Creed" games. Not sure if theres some kind of mode I can put it into to avoid getting stuck on punctuation?

Comment: You are using `limit` without `order by`. You probably want to add `order by score desc` before the `limit`.

Comment: Why are some apostrophes escaped in the result example while some are not?

Comment: You could strip all punctuation for the purposes of searching.

Comment: i thought MATCH AGAINST automatically orders by score? the output above is definitely ordered that way?

Comment: And I THINK its because magic quotes was on for one of the servers that was crawling the data :( Will try and fix later but it seems to not be fussy if its escaped or not, same thing happens. am more fussed about why its coming back with zero results when the string clearly exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the MySQL documentation for boolean searches.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html.  What you probably want to use is the * operator (similar to % wildcard).

MATCH(g_name) AGAINST ('assass*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

The number of rows in the table come into affect because of the 50% rule that MySQL applies to fulltext indexes.  If a word appears in more than 50% of the rows in the table then MySQL assumes it is too common to provide any value in narrowing down results and it is ignore.  This is typically for eliminating words like "the".

Comment: exactly what i needed, thanks! also useful to know re: the 50% rule