# MySQL fulltext autocomplete search issues

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

So I have been struggling with FULLTEXT index searches, had a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196290/mysql-fulltext-search-not-returning-expected-results) which was resolved, but it seems for some searches it works ok, and on others it doesn't

As before, looking for games in a games table, has about 25k rows, with the FULLTEXT index on g_name. I also need it to work using autocomplete as well, eg with incomplete search terms

With the search term, I explode it and then loop each iteration, appending a * onto the end eg 'grand* theft* auto* v*'

So here are some sample searches. It outputs the query at the top:

BOOLEAN MODE off, results ok

(link dead)

BOOLEAN MODE on, results not coming back as expected

(link dead)

BOOLEAN MODE off, results ok, although unsure how 'Tenchu: Shadow Assassins' is scoring more relevant to other 'assassins creed' games?

(link dead)

BOOLEAN MODE on, results not showing 'assassins creed iii'

(link dead)

Autocomplete texting partial word, BOOLEAN MODE off, NO RESULTS?!

(link dead)

Autocomplete texting partial word, BOOLEAN MODE off, ok results

(link dead)

Not sure why turning boolean mode on / off is producing such strange results. Its like I need it on for some searches and off for others, but I need a single search query. The scores seem to be just BS figures pulled from nowhere.

Also if I start adding '+' into the mix for non optional words it produces even stranger results. The whole reason I added fulltext was to make things more flexible, and return more useful results, but seems to have made things worse.

**So my question**, how do I make it return useful results every time, regardless of the nuances of that particular search term / game, and if its a partial search, or the full term. Ideally similar to how http://www.metacritic.com/ do it (top right search box)

Answer (score 0):

One course project I taught covers this topic: https://grape.ics.uci.edu/wiki/public/wiki/cs122b-2012-spring-project4#Requirement2
Solution: https://grape.ics.uci.edu/wiki/public/wiki/cs122b-2012-spring-mysql-fulltext
Pay attention to the following examples:

Prefix Search: SELECT entryID FROM ft WHERE MATCH (entry) AGAINST ('grad*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Boolean Searches: SELECT entryID FROM ft WHERE MATCH (entry) AGAINST ('+graduate -michigan' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

This approach works, but is slow and has poor ranking.

Comment: as you can see from the queries in my scripts (echoed at the top of each link above) I already use the prefix search, and already specified I used the 'must be present' + operator. doesnt answer my question as to how to get it working or why its bringing back such strange results